# メールを受信した人物が迷惑メール報告した場合にPostfix側で迷惑メール報告されたことを知る方法

Tags: mail, postfix

現在Postfixでメールマガジン配信をしようと検討しています。
配信したメールマガジンが受信者によって迷惑メール報告された場合Postfixがそれを知るすべはあるのでしょうか？
メールアドレスが存在しない場合やメールの受信箱が満杯の場合などはSMTPプロトコルのセッション内で400系や500系のエラーが返却されるので配信に失敗したという判定が可能ですが、受信者が迷惑メール迷惑メール報告する場合は既にSMTPのセッションが終了しているためエラーコードが受け取れません。受信者が迷惑メール報告をした場合例えばgmailであればgmail側からReturn-Pathにバウンスメールが送信されるというような決まりごと等があるのでしょうか？
教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

**ありません。**

迷惑メールフィルターで迷惑メールと判断された場合も、受信者が迷惑メールと報告した場合も、送信者側がそれを知る方法はありません。これらの処理は全てサイレントに(送信者に気付かれないように)行われます。

送信側がわかるのは、ブラックリストのIPから送信されている、マルウェアや悪意あるURLが含まれている等の理由でメールの受信自体を拒否された場合です。この場合は、SMTPのセッションで400/500番台で拒否されるか、送信者にリターンメールが返る事になります。

Comment: やはり分からないのですね。

Answer (score 0):

「配信不可」等のエラーを返す事はあるのかもしれませんが、相手先 (受信側) での仕様次第かと思います。
少なくとも「迷惑メールとして拒否した」ことを知らせることは無いと思います。

(メールに限らず) 拒否したことを相手に知らせてしまうと、悪意を持って行動している人に一定の効果があることを知らせてしまう事にも繋がり悪手です。

Answer (score 0):

> 配信したメールマガジンが受信者によって迷惑メール報告された場合Postfixがそれを知るすべはあるのでしょうか？

Gmailのような、受信者が受信したメールに対して「迷惑メールを報告」というような操作のことを行っているのであれば、これはSMTPとは全く関係ない話なので、当然送信側でそれを知るすべはありません。そういうことをやるような仕組みも(現時点では)ありません。

報告の結果として以後のメールがどういう扱いになるかという話であれば、

- 特に何も起きない
- 迷惑メールとして振り分け
- SMTPのセッションの時点で拒否

どういう動作になるかは実装次第です。最後のは送信側で拒否されたことはわかります。(理由までわかるかというとこれも実装次第です)